# zip dataframe and numpy array together to iterate over both elements

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate over the rows of data frame and elements in the list. For this, i try to use zip, but I get an error

```
for i, row, k in zip(d.iterrows(), ser):
```

not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

where d is my data frame and ser is a NumPy array, and I suppose to be the id of my data frame

what am I missing?

Comment: sorry, I mean not elements of the list, but elements of the numpy array

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement is trying to unpack the values of zip into 3 variables but zip return only pairs of values.

Your code should be:

```
for row, k in zip(d.iterrows(), ser):
```

But if you want the index for each of the pair then:

```
for i, row_k in enumerate(zip(d.iterrows(), ser)):
    row, k = row_k
    ...
```